# Tem algum plugin pra VS Code que mostre a cor na lateral?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter, dart

Estou programando em Dart/Flutter e gostaria que achar um plugin que faça igual ao Android Studio, reconhecendo a cor digitada e mostrando na lateral

[image: Gostaria de fazer isso no VS Code]

As cores escritas são um pouco diferentes do comum, como pode ver na img...

As vezes é `color: Colors.white`, as vezes `color: Color(0xFFFFFFAFA)` e não acho um plugin que reconheça as cores

Comment: mas no VS Code a cor já aparece, não na lateral mas ao lado do nome/rgb

Comment: @RicardoPontual o meu não aparece, acho que o VS Code não reconhece o Dart/Flutter... o código que eu coloquei ali em cima é em hexa, porem tem que por "0xFFF" na frente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução alternativa para quebra um galho:

[Color Highlight ( By Sergii Naumov)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight)

[image: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight]

*VsCode Flutter/Dart*

Settings utilizada no exemplo acima:

```
 "color-highlight.markerType": "dot-after",
 "color-highlight.matchWords": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente para o Dart e Flutter não existe plugins (ainda) que faça isso.
O VS Code trás essa opção nativa para algumas linguagens mesmo, tipo no CSS, porém no Dart e Flutter não é possível (ainda). rsrs

Também estava procurando um plugin igual um doido.

Comment: Então, um cara respondeu com uma "gambiarra", mas funciona, utilizando esse plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight e fazendo uma leva edição nas configs do VS, ajuda d+